# Service application without main icon

Tags: delphi, service

I'm writing a service without UI in Delphi XE3. I would remove the **main icon** to make smaller executable, but I could not find the method to do it. 
I tried to remove main icon from the resource file (*.res*), but when I edit the project and save, the icon is reinserted.
Can anyone give me some guidance?
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you remove the icon in the project settings in the ide?

Comment: Remove it from the .dproj file, either from the IDE or by manual editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the IDE works against you here. If you leave the `{$R *.res}` line in the project file, then the IDE will keep trying to add an icon to the .res file. I thought there was a way to tell the IDE to clear the icon, but it seems that is not the case.

In my own projects I do not let the IDE manage the .res file. I find that it's facilities for handling icons and version resources to be insufficient for my needs, and hard to automate. So instead I remove the `{$R *.res}` line and replace it with `{$R MyProject.res}`. Then I arrange that my build automation tooling creates a suitable .res file.

I think that you will need to do the same. If you let the IDE manage this for you, it's just going to get in your way. Remove the `{$R *.res}` line and wrest back control.

Comment: Not to mention those pesky Windows 98 glyph resources which are automagically included...

Comment: @JerryDodge Which you don't get in a service application because you don't include VCL units, and which aren't included in the project .res file anyway

Comment: @JerryDodge Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: Look at the resources of an empty VCL application, you'll find old fashioned glyphs.

Comment: Actually, a Delphi Windows Service Application by default uses the VCL: `Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs`

Comment: @JerryDodge So it does, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, pretty lame really. I naively assumed that they would not do anything so daft.